# format just a time for use with ui-bootstrap timepicker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, momentjs

I have a server returning a time value like so

> 14:00

The reason for this is it represents the start time of say a task that happens repetively say every monday at 14:00 so the date is irrelevant.  I want to display this value to the user when they are editing the task so that they can change it with ui-bootstraps timepicker.

The timepicker requires either an epoch, an rfc2822 or ISO 8601 date so I need to just add a random date that I can discard later for the timepicker to be able parse and display the value (which seems ridiculous seen as it is a time picker not a time on a specific day picker but whatever)

so either using the javascript date object or moment.js how can I take that value and create a valid date object with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// assume returned is the hours and minutes you get in this format: 14:00
hourData = returned.split(':');

var date = new Date();
date.setHours(hourData[0]);
date.setMinutes(hourData[1]);
```

date will be something like `Sat Jul 12 2014 14:00:13 GMT+0300 (EEST)`

Comment: works great thanks and now I know split exists, appreciate it

Answer (score 3):

As you requested a moment.js solution also:

```
var date = moment("14:00", "HH:mm").toDate();
```